# enable drag'n'drop in vagrant privisioning

Tags: drag-and-drop, vagrant, virtualbox, provisioning, vagrantfile

I want to enable drag'n'drop using the Vagrant provisioning file ("Vagrantfile"). Therefore I use the following lines:

```
vbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--clipboard", "bidirectional"]
vbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--draganddrop", "bidirectional"]
```

When I look into the settings of Virtual Box the two options are changed, but drag'n'drop still does not work. The Clipboard works in bidirectional way. How can I make drag'n'drop really make work using vagrant provisioning?

I use Virtual Box 5.0.20 and Vagrant 1.8.1

Comment: do you have virtual box guest additions installed ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried quickly to grab the full documentation for the mentioned versions, but it is hard since now there are new major versions for both Vagrant `2.X.Y` and VirtualBox `6.A.B`. So for the mentioned versions you can do the following:

```rb
vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--clipboard-mode', 'bidirectional']
vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--draganddrop', 'bidirectional']
```

You can find all modify VM arguments under [Commands overview section in VBoxManage documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-cmd-overview).

I am using Vagrant 2.2.14 and VirtualBox 6.1.22